# Copying Excel Sheets to Another Workbook at the End (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to copy a sheet from one workbook into another. I record a macro to do this and then I'm going into VBA to look at the code. I want to always copy the sheet to the end of the sheets. When I first looked at the code it had an actual number in the () after the sheets command so it would always add it as the 7th sheet instead of at the end. I changed the number to sheets.count but now get an error that the "Subscript is out of range."

```
Windows("Master Workpaper Template.xlsx").Activate
Sheets("E. Financial Stmts & Book Inc").Select
Sheets("E. Financial Stmts & Book Inc").Copy After:=Workbooks( _
    "Workbook Template.xlsm").Sheets(Sheets.Count)
```

Any ideas? This isn't the full set of code as I'm doing a few other things as well.

Comment: Try adding `Workbooks("Workbook Template.xlsm").` immediately before `Sheets.Count`, within the parentheses.

Comment: That works! Thanks! I had tried something like that before but was a bit off obviously.

Comment: Yes. If you don't **explicitly** say you want the worksheet count in your "Workbook Template.xlsm" file, Excel assumes you are referencing the `ActiveWorkbook` - in this case your "Master Workpaper Template.xlsx" - to get `Sheets.Count`.